# How to read body content from email in php using imap

Tags: php, imap-open

I am using `imap_open()` php function for reading emails from my mail account and it is working, I am able to get the header, subject, body and attachment.

But I want to get some content from body (sample body below):-

```
Ticket : 123456789
Special Instructions: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
```

Above is my email body content getting by `imap_body($mail, $id)` into html, and I want to get **Ticket** number **123456789** into a variable and similarly the value on the right of the `:` for **Special Instructions** into another variable.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-body.php

Comment: Hello @Anant, I am able to get body content into `html/Text` but I want to split it as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: explode with  new line first and then with `:`

Comment: I shortened the *lorum ipsum* string as it didn't need to be that long (scroll bars are bad generally).  Also adjusted some formatting of the question.  Usually reserve `\`` encapsulation for code blocks.

Comment: Thanks @Anant, I tried `explode with new line first and then with :`  it and it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said that you are able to fetch content, and content look like this:-

```
.....
Ticket : 123456789
Special Instructions: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
......
```

So to get elements separatly:-

First explode with `\n` (new line)

Now you will get an array. Now apply `foreach()` and explode again with `:`

Note:- you need to use `strpos()` to get first occurrence of `:` and then explode string through that position (if more than one `:` are there in array elements)

Comment: Hello @Anant, it is working when `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit` does not have `:` into it but it is not woking in case when `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur :  adipiscing elit` has either `:` or `new line`, please answer.

Comment: For explode by first colon `explode(':', $str, 2)` is working.

Comment: But still finding a better solution when `Special Instructions` text also has new line.

Comment: No the case is different, because I want to split by each line such as `Ticket : "" , From : "" , Date : "" , Location :  "" etc.` to get individual line and at this time `Special Instructions: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br> consectetur adipiscing elit` also split into two.

Answer (score 2):

I would say, study the pattern of your email body

For example if

```
Ticket : 123456789
Special Instructions: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

is all the body contains, then I will use the explode function to fish out the parts I need using the ':' as my delimiter
I will look like this.

```
$body_parts = explode(':',$body);
```

then

```
$ticket_id = trim($body_parts[1]);
$special_instructions = trim($body_parts[3]);
```

If this doesn't capture it, the using REGEX will be the go-to option.

Hope it Helps

Comment: Hello, I can't use `explode` here, because I posted only some content of mail in actual the email has more content above and below it, please post `REGEX` method to get these values.

Comment: then use Ticket and Special Instructions as the delimiters if luckily they appear just once - a mean way of getting what you want i guess

Comment: As i said that first explode with new line and then explode with `:` (With your each array element)